# Notification not show in Device tray by using Firebase notification

Tags: php, cordova, firebase, ionic-framework, firebase-cloud-messaging

I use [cordova-plugin-fcm](https://github.com/fechanique/cordova-plugin-fcm) plugin for send notification for my IONIC App. I need to send image in notification in my application, So I use **notificationOptions** in my PHP code.

Without  the **notificationOptions** notification show in my Device tray, but when I try to implement **notificationOptions** in my PHP code, then Notification not show in my Device tray but I get in my console log:

```
{"notificationOptions":"{\"largeIcon\":\"https:\\/\\/avatars2.githubusercontent.com\\/u\\/1174345?v=3&s=96\",
\"smallIcon\":\"mipmap\\/icon\",
\"id\":4,\"text\":\"Test message\",
\"title\":\"Title test\",
\"autoCancel\":true}",
"dataValuesToGetWhenClickedOn":"111","wasTapped":false}
```

PHP Code:

```
    `<?php
    $msg = array
    (
        "dataValuesToGetWhenClickedOn" => 111,
        'notificationOptions' => array(
            'title' => "Title test",
            'id' => 4,
            'text' => "Test message",
            'smallIcon' => "mipmap/icon",
            'largeIcon'   => "https://avatars2.githubusercontent.com/u/1174345?v=3&s=96",
            'autoCancel'  => true
        )
    );
    //print_r($msg); // exit();
    $fields = array
    (
        'to'  => "c5clRYgB1vo:APA91bGTlyTQur2S9b5iksc16-T0KzwV9Ein0n0RSafgDBdgxVKjhGQU0BLPmvnJVShCKDhlpeJCpHthmRglQcegT",
        'data'          => $msg
    );
    $data =  json_encode($fields);
    $ch = curl_init("https://fcm.googleapis.com/fcm/send");
    $header = array('Accept: application/json','Content-Type: application/json',
    "Authorization: key=---Api Key---");
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $header);
    curl_setopt( $ch,CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false );
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
    curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $data);
    //curl_exec($ch);
    if(curl_exec($ch) === false)
    {
        echo 'Curl error: ' . curl_error($ch);
    }
    else
    {
        $result = curl_exec($ch );
        curl_close( $ch );
        echo $result;
    }
    ?>`
```

Please help me. I want to know that what I am doing wrong.

Comment: Hi. Can you point out where you got the `notificationOptions` parameter from?

Comment: I can get the `notificationOptions` parameter from [cordova-plugin-firebase-extended-notification](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-firebase-extended-notification)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It solves my problem. If any one face same problem,

Please follow the link:

https://github.com/andrehtissot/cordova-plugin-firebase-extended-notification-app-example